# Google Apps script event EventGuest does not have .getEmail()

Tags: javascript, object, for-loop, google-apps-script

Grabbing google calander events into drive sheets worked like a charm with some copy paste code...

But my attempts at extracting event guests from Google calendar into a spreadsheet met with little success. See screenshot. Here's the code.

```
function getEmailsFromArray(guestsArray){
var guestEmails = []
for (var i=1;i<guestsArray.length;i++) {
  guestEmails.push(i.getEmail()) // i does not have getEmail()
}
return guestsArray; }
```

And this is called as a lamda(?) when preparing the data inserted into

```
 getEmailsFromArray(events[i].getGuestList())
```

[Here's the doc for getGuestList()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/event-guest)

Is EventGuest not an object with functions but a string? Am I perhaps not stepping through the array properly? Should I cry uncle?

[image: debugging calander events]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a few syntax issues, try this...

```
function getEmailsFromArray(guestsArray){
var guestEmails = [];
for (var i=0;i<guestsArray.length;i++) {
  guestEmails.push(guestsArray[i].getEmail());
}
return guestEmails; }
```

Comment: Thank you. I've apparently forgotten the difference between arrays and objects.